# two independent numbers from a unifrom distribution

Tags: probability

I am working on a problem and I have the solution but I have a question on one of the steps.

We choose two numbers $B$ and $C$ from the interval [0,1] with a uniform distribution. Note that point (B,C) is then chosen at random from the unit square. Find the probability that $B+C \le \frac{1}{3}$

From here it says to let H be the half plane $B+C \le \frac{1}{3}$ and $S$ the unit square. I understand that the ratio of the area of $H \cap S $ and $S$ will be the answer but I am confused on why this becomes $\frac{1}{18}$ or rather where they get the $\frac{1}{18}$ from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What else would it be?

$S$ is the rectangle $(0,0)(1,0)(1,1)(0,1)$, whose area is clearly $1$.

$H\cap S$ is the right triangle $(0,0)(\tfrac 13,0)(0,\tfrac 13)$, whose area is $\tfrac 12\tfrac 13\tfrac 13$.

Comment: I see. I was forgetting to count for the $\frac{1}{2}$